# variable name introspection in Python

Tags: python, metaprogramming

Is it possible to dynamically determine the name of a variable in Python?

For example, I sometimes have the following situation:

```
name = foo if bar else baz
type = alpha or bravo

D = {
    "name": name,
    "type": type
}
```

It would be nice if duplication there could be reduced with something like `D = makedict(name, type)`.

Somewhat relatedly, it would sometimes be helpful for a function to know its own name:

```
class Item(object):

    def item_create(self, item):
        dispatch("create", item)

    def item_delete(self, item):
        dispatch("delete", item)
```

Here duplication might be reduced by passing something like `__methodname__` instead of explicitly repeating "create" and "delete", respectively.
(I assume a decorator could be used for this, but that seems like overkill.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the general case, you cannot deduce the name from a value (there might be no name, there might be multiple ones, etc); when you call your hypothetical `makedict(name)`, the **value** of `name` is what `makedict` receives, so (again, in the general case) it cannot discern what name (if any) the value came from. You could introspect your caller's namespaces to see if you're lucky enough to hit a special case where the value does let you infer the name (e.g., you receive `23`, and there's only one name throughout the namespaces of interest which happens to have a value of `23`!), but that's clearly a fragile and iffy architecture.  Plus, in your first example case, it's absolutely guaranteed that the special case will **not** occur -- the value in `name` is exactly the same as in either `foo` or `baz`, so it's 100% certain that the name for that value will be hopelessly ambiguous.

You could take a completely different tack, such as calling `makedict('name type', locals())` (passing `locals()` explicitly might be obviated with dark and deep introspection magic, but that's not the most solid choice in general) -- pass in the **names** (and namespaces, I suggest!) and have `makedict` deduce the **values**, which is obviously a much more solid proposition (since each name has exactly one value, but **not** viceversa).  I.e.:

```
def makedict(names, *namespaces):
  d = {}
  for n in names.split():
    for ns in namespaces:
      if n in ns:
        d[n] = ns[n]
        break
    else:
      d[n] = None  # or, raise an exception
```

If you're keen on digging out the namespaces by introspection, rather than have them cleanly specified by the caller, look at [inspect.getouterframes](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect#inspect.getouterframes) -- but I suggest you reconsider.

The second issue you raise is quite different (though you could use `inspect` functions again to introspect the caller's name, or a function's own name -- what a peculiar idea!).  What's in common in the two cases is that you're using extremely powerful and dangerous machinery to do a job that could be done much more simply (easier to ensure correctness, easier to debug any problems, easier to test, etc, etc) -- far from having decorators be "overkill", they're **far** simpler and more explicit than the introspection you propose.  If you have a zillion methods all of the form:

```
def item_blah(self, item):
    dispatch("blah", item)
```

the simplest way to create them might be:

```
class Item(object): pass

def _makedispcall(n):
  def item_whatever(self, item):
    dispatch(n, item)
  item_whatever.__name__ = 'item_' + n
  return item_whatever

for n in 'create delete blah but wait theres more'.split():
  setattr(Item, 'item_' + n, _makedispcall(n))
```

Avoiding repetition is an excellent idea, but runtime introspection is not generally the best way to implement that idea, and Python offers many alternative ways to such implementation.

Comment: Thanks, this is very insightful. I expected that there'd be no simple solution, and ultimately agree that it's no worth the trouble.

Answer (score 4):

In general, you can't do this in Python, because Python has objects, not variables.

If I have

```
L1 = [1,2]
L2 = L1
```

Then, `L1` and `L2` both refer to the same object.  It has no *single* name.

Similarly:

```
def f1(): pass
f2 = f1
```

Now the function has no single name, and as such, you can't find out "the" name of the function.

An object in Python can be referenced by many names - when the reference count of an object goes to zero, Python frees the memory for it.

Comment: Yeah, I had realized this, but figured there might be some way to figure it out nevertheless. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want for functions:

```
>>> def blagnorf():
    pass

>>> print blagnorf.__name__
blagnorf
```

But not for variables, unfortunately. You could probably write a preprocessor for your python code to do it for you, though...

Note that you can do this in Scheme/Lisp with the macro system they have there.

Comment: This only works outside the respective function though. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can get the stack trace and get a reference to the current function being executed that way, from inside the function. or you can also do "blagnorf.__name__" inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you get a hankering to make a gazillion simple methods whose internals only differ according to the method's name, you probably should reconsider your interface. Instead, you could do this:

```
class Item(object):
    def item_action(self, action, item):
        dispatch(action, item)
```

where action could be "create", "delete", etc.

Comment: I agree - unfortunately, I'm not in control of the interface here.